# Merging arrays with for loop in python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, merge

I want to merge two arrays in to one array in an alternating sequence (arr1,arr2,arr1,arr2,....). After two hours i got this far by trying different methods like concatenate or append or two interlocked "for loops".

As i want to use this regardless of the format (string or integer arrays) i wanted to use a "for loop". My try gives me the correct order, but has some elements missing as the counter isn´t perfect. So what can i do correct that?

Example:

```
arr1 = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29]
arr2 = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30]
merged = [None]*2*len(arr1)
v = range(0,len(arr1))
for i in v[::2]:
    merged[i] = arr1[i]
    merged[i+1]=arr2[i]

print(merged)
```

gives
[1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 17, 18, 21, 22, 25, 26, 29, 30, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

Comment: `merged = [x for tpl in zip(arr1, arr2) for x in tpl]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could easily be achieved like this:

```
result = [];
arr1 = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29]
arr2 = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30]

for i in range(len(arr1)): 
    result.append(arr1[i]) 
    result.append(arr2[i]) 
    
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply merge array by using addition operator for example

```
result_array=array1+array2
```

Then you can sort it to get your result

```
result_array.sort()
```

Comment: they want to interlace the values

Comment: seems like i am so impatient. I need to slow down.

Comment: sorting is not really the answer... it may work in this particular case but it's obviously not a reliable way to achieve what's expected

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, I need to write another one to make it work but you posted the right one already.

Answer (score 0):

To merge them such that the values alternate you can simply zip the two lists and iterating over the zipped object will return a tuple with an item from one list and an item at the same index from the other list (order of passing arrays to `zip` is important) and you can extend your list by that returned tuple:

```py
arr1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29]
arr2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30]

merged = []
for values in zip(arr1, arr2):
    merged.extend(values)
```

Alternatively you can use a simple list comprehension:

```py
merged = [x for tpl in zip(arr1, arr2) for x in tpl]
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping with your solution you need to iterate up to the size of the target list, not the smaller one. You also need to divide `i` by 2 to fit `arr` indices

```
arr1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29]
arr2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30]
merged = [None] * 2 * len(arr1)
for i in range(0, len(merged) - 1, 2):
    merged[i] = arr1[i // 2]
    merged[i + 1] = arr2[i // 2]

print(merged)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions works;

Another way to get desired result is;

```
arr1 = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29]
arr2 = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30]
merged = []
for i in range(0,len(arr1)):
    merged.append(arr1[i])
    merged.append(arr2[i])
print(merged)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried a variant from another comment wihich is similar to yous and that works.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr1 = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29]
arr2 = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30]
merged = []
[merged.extend([a1, a2]) for a1, a2 in zip(arr1, arr2)]
print(merged)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use numpy, combination of vstack and [flatten](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29])
arr2 = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30])
result = np.vstack((arr1, arr2)).flatten("F")

print(result)
```

Result:

> [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
> 25 26 27 28 29 30]